# How to bind the value of select to an input when it's dinamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with a Js/Rails code. I have a form that is created dynamically when I click a button(It can create multiple of this forms in the same page), it contains a select that have an ID that is never the same. I need to put some value into an input according to the select value. In the first form It works perfectly but later in the other forms it doesn't work. Like I said, I don't have access to the ID's because those are created in rails.

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
<div>
  <div class="divSelect">
  <select id="1470190840697_ad_type">
    <option>Element1</option>
    <option>Element2</option>
    <option>Element3</option>
    <option>Element4</option>
    <option>Element5</option>
    <option>Element6</option>
  </select>
</div>
  <div class="divInput">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<div>

  //This is dynamically created
  <div class="divSelect">
    <select id="1470190846932_ad_type">
      <option>Element1</option>
      <option>Element2</option>
      <option>Element3</option>
      <option>Element4</option>
      <option>Element5</option>
      <option>Element6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript - jQuery**

```
$('.test').on('change',$('.divSelect').children('select'),function(){
  updateTime();
});

function updateTime() {
  var tipoPauta = { 'Element1':1,
                    'Element2':2,
                    'Element3':3,
                    'Element4':4,
                    'Element5':5,
                    'Element6':6
                   }

  var select = $('.divSelect').children('select');
  $('.divInput').children('input').val(tipoPauta[select.val()]);
};
```

[JSBIN CODE](http://jsbin.com/lazocufefu/edit?html,js,output)

Thanks a lot! I'm crazy with this problem.

Comment: Delegated event handlers using `on()` should have **a string** as the second argument, not a jQuery collection

Comment: You can use relative paths to get to the element you need... eg "find the parent form, then within this form, find the child with a class of X" so that you you only find the closest input text-field to the select-box you are using.

Comment: adeneo Can you explain me why please? Thank you Taryn East!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @adeneo mentioned, you need to specify a string as a selector as the second argument. Also to update the correct input element, your code should be something like

```
$('.test').on('change',  '.divSelect' ,function(){
  var $select = $(this).find('select');
  updateTime($(this), $select);
});



function updateTime($divelement, $selectelement) {
  var tipoPauta = { 'Element1':1,
                    'Element2':2,
                'Element3':3,
                'Element4':4,
                'Element5':5,
                'Element6':6
               }

  var $input = $divelement.next().children('input');

  $input.val(tipoPauta[$selectelement.val()]);
};
```

Comment: Great! I get it, your solution works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Can you explain me please why the $name variables? What is the difference with the normal name variables?

Comment: There is no difference per se. It is just a convention that is somewhat widely used to prefix the variables that store jQuery objects with a `$` sign. The normal name variables are used to store classic javascript object. 

It does not make a difference one way or the other but just a convention to quickly know whether you can use jQuery functions on a variable or not. I also usually camel case the variables which I forgot to do in the above example.